# The probability that there exists finite N such that N products of i.i.d. random variable is smaller than some threshold is 1

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $X$ be a random variable which has a probability distribution $\mathcal{P}$ where the support of $\mathcal{P}$ is (0,1). Let $\{X_n\}_{n\ge0}$ be a sequence of random variable where $X_{n}\overset{i.i.d.}{\sim} X$. Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $\Pi_{n=1}^{N}(X_n)\le 0.5$, otherwise let $N$ be infinite.

I would like to show $\mathcal{P}(N<\infty)=1.$

My attempt: I have gotten hint from here to apply Borel-Cantelli Lemma. Let $E_N=\{\Pi_{n=1}^{N}(X_n)\le 0.5\}$. Then I should first show $\sum\mathcal{P}(E_N)<\infty$. But we do not know $\mathcal{P}(E_N)$ and even we show $\sum\mathcal{P}(E_N)<\infty$, Borel-Cantelli Lemma says the number of the events to occur is finite, which is different from what I am looking for. (I am looking for the probability that there exists finite $N$ such that $\Pi_{n=1}^{N}(X_n)\le 0.5$ is 1.)

Could anyone give me a guidance or hint to follow? I am quite stuck in thinking right now, even not sure how to start the proof.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be actually simpler to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma with $E_N=\left\{\prod_{n=1}^NX_n>1/2\right\}$ and to show that $\sum_{N\geqslant 1}\mathbb P\left(E_N\right)$ is finite (this can be shown by Markov's inequality). Note that $(E_N)$ is an  non-decreasing sequence, so $\limsup_N E_N$ has a nice form and you know its probability.

Comment: I really appreciate for the answer. It helps a lot!

Comment: You are welcome! You can upvote it and/or mark it as accepted if you are satisfied. Welcome to Math Stack Exchange by the way!